# IndexError when replacing missing values with mode using groupby in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, missing-data

I have a dataset which requires missing value treatment.

```
 Column                      Missing Values

 Complaint_ID                    0         
 Date_received                   0         
 Transaction_Type                0         
 Complaint_reason                0         
 Company_response              22506         
 Date_sent_to_company            0         
 Complaint_Status                0         
 Consumer_disputes             7698
```

Now the problem is, when I try to replace the missing `values` with mode of other `columns` using `groupby`:

Code:

```
data11["Company_response"] = 
data11.groupby("Complaint_reason").transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mode() 
[0]))["Company_response"]

data11["Consumer_disputes"] = 
data11.groupby("Transaction_Type").transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mode() 
[0]))["Consumer_disputes"]
```

I get the following error:

### Stacktrace

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-89-8de6a010a299>", line 1, in <module>
    data11["Company_response"] = data11.groupby("Complaint_reason").transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mode()[0]))["Company_response"]

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.py", line 3741, in transform
    return self._transform_general(func, *args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.py", line 3699, in _transform_general
    res = path(group)

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.py", line 3783, in <lambda>
    lambda x: func(x, *args, **kwargs), axis=self.axis)

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 4360, in apply
    ignore_failures=ignore_failures)

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 4456, in _apply_standard
    results[i] = func(v)

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.py", line 3783, in <lambda>
    lambda x: func(x, *args, **kwargs), axis=self.axis)

  File "<ipython-input-89-8de6a010a299>", line 1, in <lambda>
    data11["Company_response"] = data11.groupby("Complaint_reason").transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mode()[0]))["Company_response"]

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 601, in __getitem__
    result = self.index.get_value(self, key)

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2434, in get_value
    return libts.get_value_box(s, key)

  File "pandas\_libs\tslib.pyx", line 923, in pandas._libs.tslib.get_value_box (pandas\_libs\tslib.c:18843)

  File "pandas\_libs\tslib.pyx", line 939, in pandas._libs.tslib.get_value_box (pandas\_libs\tslib.c:18560)

IndexError: ('index out of bounds', 'occurred at index Consumer_disputes')
```

I have checked the `length` of the `dataframe`and all of its columns and it is same: 43266.

I have also found a question similar to this but does not have correct answer: [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42404776/pandas-fill-in-missing-values-by-mode-having-index-out-of-bounds-error)

Please help resolve the error.

> IndexError: ('index out of bounds', 'occurred at index Consumer_disputes')

Here is a snapshot of the dataset if it helps in any way: [Dataset Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7xIp.png)

I am using the below code successfully. But it does not serve my purpose exactly. Helps to fill the missing values though.

```
data11['Company_response'].fillna(data11['Company_response'].mode()[0], 
inplace=True)
data11['Consumer_disputes'].fillna(data11['Consumer_disputes'].mode()[0], 
inplace=True)
```

Edit1: (Attaching Sample)

Input Given:
[image: InputImage]

Expected Output:
[image: OutputImage]

You can see that the missing values for company-response of Tr-1 and Tr-3 are filled by taking mode of Complaint-Reason.
And similarly for the Consumer-Disputes by taking mode of transaction-type, for Tr-5.

The below snippet consists of the dataframe and the code for those who want to replicate and give it a try.

### Replication Code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data11=pd.DataFrame({'Complaint_ID':['Tr-1','Tr-2','Tr-3','Tr-4','Tr-5','Tr-6'],
                    'Transaction_Type':['Mortgage','Credit card','Bank account or service','Debt collection','Credit card','Mortgage'],
                    'Complaint_reason':['Loan servicing, payments, escrow account','Incorrect information on credit report',"Cont'd attempts collect debt not owed","Cont'd attempts collect debt not owed",'Payoff process','Loan servicing, payments, escrow account'],
                    'Company_response':[np.nan,'Company chooses not to provide a public response',np.nan,'Company believes it acted appropriately as authorized by contract or law','Company has responded to the consumer and the CFPB and chooses not to provide a public response','Company disputes the facts presented in the complaint'],
                    'Consumer_disputes':['Yes','No','No','No',np.nan,'Yes']})

data11.isnull().sum()

data11["Company_response"] = data11.groupby("Complaint_reason").transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mode()[0]))["Company_response"]
data11["Consumer_disputes"] = data11.groupby("Transaction_Type").transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mode()[0]))["Consumer_disputes"]
```

Comment: the question literally died last time, i edited it, left comments but no one answered for almost 6 days, so unfortunately i had to post it again as i do not have any bounties to offer, so guys if you find it interesting and are unable to solve it, please upvote the question so that it might interest others as well...

Comment: Could you add a small input sample and the expected output

Comment: the question did not "literally die" - this is a metaphor. it figuratively died!

Comment: @JoshFriedlander haha... yes Josh... got a bit carried away i guess...

Comment: :) as for your question - it would help if you could post like 5 rows of your data, or made-up equivalents - that screenshot is the right idea but text is much easier to work with than an image

Comment: Can't reproduce it. Can you try calling `data11.groupby("Complaint_reason").transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mode() 
[0]))["Company_response"]` (without adding it as a column) and seeing what its shape is?

Comment: @JoshFriedlander same error bro...

Comment: What version of pandas are you using?  Upgrade pandas?   I did not duplicate your error with giving data11 and statement with groupby.

Comment: @ScottBoston I have edited the code, now you will be able to replicate the issue, I had ealier put in empty string instead of nan. Sorry!!  And the pandas version is 0.20.1.

Comment: @JoshFriedlander you'll be able to replicate the issue now... i have updated the code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
data11["Company_response"] = data11.groupby("Complaint_reason")['Company_response'].transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mode()[0]))

data11["Consumer_disputes"] = data11.groupby("Transaction_Type")['Consumer_disputes'].transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mode()[0]))
```

Comment: Thanks Scott... :)

Answer (score 5):

The error is raised because for at least one of the groups the values in corresponding aggregated columns contains only np.nan values. In this case `pd.Series([np.nan]).mode()` returns an empty series which leads to an error when you take the first value.

So, you may use something like `transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mode()[0] if not x.mode().empty else "Empty") )`.

Comment: On running this I get the exact error mentioned in the question. Mikhail can you please replicate it on your local (I have given the code in the question for replication) , I am really stuck on this since long now..

Comment: Could you provide a full stacktrace when you run it along with a self-sufficient code to create an input data for that?

Comment: Mikhail I have mentioned the self sufficient code with input and the stacktrace both in the question itself..

Comment: I meant the stacktrace when you run `data11.groupby("Transaction_Type").transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mode()[0]))`. I want to be sure it's indeed the same which is very unlikely. Also, I didn't find code snippet to create an input dataframe. I can't take it from screenshot of an excel file.

Comment: Mikhail please observe carefully I have mentioned the **Replication Code** (in bold letters below the excel screenshots) with the input dataframe... and the stacktrace I get when I run `data11.groupby("Transaction_Type").transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mode()[0]))` is very long it cannot be put in the comments section, so let me highlight the stacktrace also in the question itself in bolds.  Note: the stacktrace is exactly same for the code you have asked me to run.

Comment: Your code starts with `data11.isnull().sum()` which is not defined above.

Comment: Ok, I've fixed the answer

Comment: Thank you for the efforts Mikhail, but when I run, `data11["Company_response"] = data11.groupby("Complaint_reason").transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mode()[0] if not x.mode().empty else "Empty"))
data11["Consumer_disputes"] = data11.groupby("Transaction_Type").transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mode()[0] if not x.mode().empty else "Empty"))`  , the Consumer_disputes column gets messed up.  Scott's answer did the trick for me. But thank you for all the efforts :)

Answer (score 1):

@Mikhail Berlinkov is almost certainly correct. I was able to reproduce your error, and then avoid it by using `dropna()`:

```
data11.groupby("Transaction-Type").transform(
    lambda x: x.fillna(x.mode() [0]))["Consumer-disputes"]  
# Returns IndexError

data11.dropna().groupby("Transaction-Type").transform(
    lambda x: x.fillna(x.mode() [0]))["Consumer-disputes"]  
# Works
```

Comment: Thanks for the input Josh but this fill further mess up the dataframe. Try it for yourself and see the results...